# Linker ignores options from g++

Tags: g++, ld, stdcall

I'm trying to create object file without @-suffix with g++:

`g++ -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -c test.cpp`

or

`g++ -Wl,--kill-at -c test.cpp`

But none of options works.

Using:
MinGW32 with g++ v4.4, ld v2.19.1

Thanks!